# How to align items horizontal in form field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a sample form just under a table. Like below
[image]

I want to strech the form field as same length with the table and I want to align form items horizontally.

My css is:

```
.buttonFooter {
    background-color: gray;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And the code is:

```
<Card className='buttonFooter'>
                <Form className='buttonFooter'>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" value={firstName}></input>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" value={lastName}></input>
                    <Button>Add New Customer</Button>
                </Form>
            </Card>
```

If I delete form tag and just use css.class for the card then it works (horizontal alignment) but I need to use a form to get the value of input box and send it to a method with button click. How can I align them horizontal and enlarge it with same size with table ?

Comment: For `flex-direction` to work, the `display` must be set to `display: flex`, not `inline-block`. Also, what HTML is rendered by that component, because CSS works on the resultant HTML, which is similar to - but *not* the same as - the component's jsx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the width in css using:

`width: x;` (x being the width of your table)

I haven't tested it but you can try setting `display` to `flex` or `inline-flex` instead of `inline-block`

Comment: thanks for the answer I accepted it man. Another problem is I cannot write anything to inputboxes I mean it is showing good but I cannot write anything to that. Do you know why ? Maybe I am missing some property in <input> field

Comment: @ChrisGarsonn in React using `value=""` in an input will set the value permenantly so that it cannot be changed. Use `defaultValue=""` instead.